# Error while Changing the connection string dynamically

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, connection-string, entity-model

Im having this problem when changing my entities connection string.

here is the code:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                        sqlBuilder.DataSource = @"KURT-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
                        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "KurtDB";
                        sqlBuilder.UserID = "Admin";
                        sqlBuilder.Password = "123456";
                        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

                        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
                        entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
                        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();
                        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl";

                        this.Entities.Connection.ConnectionString = conn.Connection.ConnectionString = entityBuilder.ConnectionString.ToString();
```

when it tries to change the connection string its giving me an InvalidOperationEsception.

error details:
No modifications to connection are permitted after the metadata has been registered either by opening a connection or constructing the connection with a MetadataWorkspace.

Any help its leaving me speachless....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that in your example, `this.Entities` is an instance of an Entity Framework Object Context.

The error message means that you cannot simply assign the new connection string to the `Connection` property of the `Entities` object.

Instead, try passing it as a constructor parameter:

- locate the line where you instantiate Entities:
  `this.Entities = new ...();`
- change it to something like this:
  `this.Entities = new ...(entityBuilder.ConnectionString.ToString());`

Comment: i tried but it still keeps the same connection string which it was assigned with...


KurtDBEntities conn = new KurtDBEntities(sqlBuilder.ConnectionString.ToString());

then it goes through this constructor:

public KurtDBEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "KurtDBEntities")

        {

            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

            OnContextCreated();

        }


And im having an argumentException with the details:

Comment: Bdw new to stackoverflow so dont really know how to make proper formattin sorry...